# How to check in thymeleaf if session exist?

Tags: javascript, java, session, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

How can I check in thymeleaf if these sessions exist on my controller? Yet if not, it redirects to the login page.

Here is my java code:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public static ModelAndView index(HttpSession session) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("index");
    session.setAttribute("mySessionAttribute", "kkkkddk");
    session.setAttribute("kokey", "kokeyyyy");
    session.setAttribute("ds", "kkkkk");
    return mav;
}
```

And here is the thymeleaf. It doesn't seem to be working properly since it keeps on redirecting to login page even if the sessions have values.  I also tried to change the second condition to th:unless but not working also.

```html
<tr th:each="var : ${session}">
    <td th:if="${var.value == null">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "/login";
        </script>
    </td>
    <td th:if="${var.value != null}">
        <td th:text="${var.value}"></td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post your spring-security file?

Comment: I dont have any

Comment: I have no idea. How to do it?